# как перебирать строки в текстовом файле и записывать их в словарь Python

Tags: python, dict, словарь

Мне необходимо с помощью Python открыть файл, взять из него первую строку, добавить в словарь, а со словарем провести какие-то изменения.

открываю и читаю файл:

```
password = open('pass.txt')
password = password.readline()
```

далее мне необходимо эту строку добавить в словарь:

```
data = {
    'login_name' : login ,
    'login_password' : password 
}
```

Вопрос: Как реализовать цикл, чтобы бралась строка, вставлялась в словарь и если словарь не отрабатывает(Условие для проверки у меня есть), то должна вставится следующая строка и так по аналогии?

Answer (score 0):

Например,так:

```
password = open('a.txt')
while True:
    password1 = password.readline()
    if password1:
         добавление в словарь 
         if условие выполнено:
             # Больше не считываем из файла, выходим из цикла
             break 
    # Получили EOF - пустую строку, выходим из цикла
    else:
        break
password.close()
```

Comment: если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).